# Installing upgraded CodeIgniter-4 on shared host directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Having rebuilt an app originally built in Codeigniter-3 in CI4, which runs fine locally on XAMPP with PHP 8.1, how does one upload install it on a shared host?

I see there is no index.php in the root folder, just a preload.php...
I found I could get a response by browsing routes in the public directory, e.g. https://ijump-trampoline.co.za/clearwater2/public/booking - but am pretty sure that is not the way to do things. And I don't know if the `CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException` `Core.enabledZlibOutputCompression` that I got then has to do with using an improper URL, or I'm about to discover CI4 requires some library the shared host, Xneelo, doesn't support.

I have also tried placing an index.php file with `include 'public/index.php';` in the root directory but have removed that again.

Currently, I'm getting a HTTP 500 error even when trying to access the url listed above and have no idea why - and at a loss for how to proceed.

The old Codeigniter-3 version of the system is still running at https://ijump-trampoline.co.za/clearwater/booking and the plan was to replace that with the new CI4 version and keep the existing URL structure. (There are to be other branches with their own installations in neighboring directories in the same TLD.)

Comment: This is a bit unclear: Are you installing CI4 via composer? Or just copying files from your localhost? How is your localhost install (via composer or manual)? Use shared host's CPanel to rename the old (CI3) website and make a 1:1 copy from localhost to the shared server. Keep in mind http versus https issues... Compare if both server setups are the same (php, mysql, CI). To setup a fresh CI4 install with composer, you might need to ask your hosting to enable SSH access for your hosted domain(s). Start debugging, if all this fails

Comment: P.S.: also read this: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75908.html and several other forum post, just google your question

Comment: make sure your hosting has php8.1 installed: https://xneelo.co.za/help-centre/products-and-services/software/ and https://xneelo.co.za/help-centre/website/php-upgrade/

Comment: @Vickel that form thread assumes a coupleof things, including that the CodeIgnitor installtion will run in the top level root of a domain, not a directory of the domain, also that there will only be one installation of of CI in the domain - I want to run a couple. That makes me think perhaps I need to place some kind of redirect to the /public folder in the root of the domain (which e.g. also contains a WordPress installation in a separate directory accessible from the root).

Comment: *installation will run in the top level root of a domain, not a directory of the domain, also that there will only be one installation of CI in the domain - I want to run a couple* Each domain, one CI installation! but you can have different versions installed for different domains on the same hosting provider account

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter 4 has many differences with Codeigniter 3. The best way to put your Codeigniter 4 in shared hosting is to take everything inside the Codeigniter 4 public folder and put it in your public_html folder on cpanel, then put the put your other app, system and other folder and files in another folder outside the public_html (I usually create a new folder naming it after my project). Then in the index.php in your public_html folder

```
require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

to reflect your new folder and app such as

```
require FCPATH . '../myapp/app/Config/Paths.php';
```

Assuming you named your folder myapp and put your project files there.

Comment: Thanks @user32008048, I already run a WordPress installation from the root of the domain and want the CI installation(s) and its routes to run in a sub-directory only - so I will try to put the public folder's contents there and adjust the requires accordingly.

Comment: My advice to you is to not do that. You might be compromising your ci app like that. Can't you just create a new sub-domain for the ci app then in there you'll put your public folder content. Then in your home folder you create a folder called myapp and in there you put all other folders. After that you can just adjust your index.php line to paths.